# Why _lstm_ops.dll can't be found in the tensorflow, it actually in my path

Tags: python, dll, tensorflow, path, gpu

Computer : Win10 Home edition

Editor :Anaconda / Spyder

Tensorflow :tensorflow-gpu

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

tf.set_random_seed(1)

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data/', one_hot=True)

lr = 0.001
training_iters = 100000
batch_size = 128

n_inputs = 28   
n_steps = 28    
n_hidden_units = 128   
n_classes = 10      

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs]) 
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes]) 

weights = {    
    'in': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_inputs, n_hidden_units])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_units, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'in': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_hidden_units, ])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_classes, ]))
}


def RNN(X, weights, biases):
    # hidden layer for input to cell

    X = tf.reshape(X, [-1, n_inputs])
    X_in = tf.matmul(X, weights['in']) + biases['in']
    X_in = tf.reshape(X_in, [-1, n_steps, n_hidden_units])

    # cell
    ##########################################

    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_units)

    init_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)

    outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X_in, 
    initial_state=init_state, time_major=False)

    outputs = tf.unstack(tf.transpose(outputs, [1,0,2]))
    results = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out'] 

pred = RNN(x, weights, biases)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(cost)

correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    step = 0
    while step * batch_size < training_iters:
        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        batch_xs = batch_xs.reshape([batch_size, n_steps, n_inputs])
        sess.run([train_op], feed_dict={x: batch_xs,y: batch_ys,})

        if step % 20 == 0:
            print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: batch_xs,y: batch_ys,}))
        step += 1
```

## then I run this RNN code , it show me a confusing error said _lstm_ops.dll not found ... however I very sure this .dll file actually stored in this path (C:\Users\清山\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\opencvtest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\rnn\python\ops_lstm_ops.dll) anyone can help me ? QQ

```
 packages\keras\engine\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from .training import Model

  File "C:\Users\清山\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\opencvtest\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .. import callbacks as cbks

  File "C:\Users\清山\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\opencvtest\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector

  File "C:\Users\清山\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\opencvtest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import cudnn_rnn

  File "C:\Users\清山\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\opencvtest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\cudnn_rnn\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.cudnn_rnn.python.ops.cudnn_rnn_ops import CudnnGRU

  File "C:\Users\清山\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\opencvtest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\cudnn_rnn\python\ops\cudnn_rnn_ops.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops import lstm_ops

  File "C:\Users\清山\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\opencvtest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\rnn\python\ops\lstm_ops.py", line 36, in <module>
    resource_loader.get_path_to_datafile("_lstm_ops.so"))

  File "C:\Users\清山\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\opencvtest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\util\loader.py", line 55, in load_op_library
    ret = load_library.load_op_library(path)

  File "C:\Users\清山\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\opencvtest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\load_library.py", line 64, in load_op_library
    None, None, error_msg, error_code)

NotFoundError: C:\Users\清山\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\opencvtest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\rnn\python\ops\_lstm_ops.dll not found
```

BTW I get some info said chinese word in my path will get error,but I run others code like CNN didn't show this kind of errors !?
and I am also tryimg change my chinese word into eng word about the path,but my computer is Home Edition that can't let me change it... Orz.Orz.

Answer (score 0):

Please know that English is not my native language, and I may make some confusing mistakes.

I was having the same problem as you.
To get straight to the point, the reason of the problem was the Chinese character as you think.

I am Japanese, and I used Chinese character as my username.
Therefore, my path included Chinese character like you.

I made new account on windows, which name does not include Chinese character.
then I re-installed everything.

thereupon, my cord (tf.contrib.data.Dataset...) worked.

Maybe some modules do not accommodate Unicode, while others do.

If you are going to add account on windows 10,
you may have problem because sometimes windows 10 has bugs about that operation.
At such times, try [net User qingshan /add] in command prompt.
You can create new account.